# Api Gateway and Sharing Service Models

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, microservices, api-design, api-gateway

The short version of my question is that I'm trying to wrap my head around how models are "shared" between an API Gateway and internal microservices. I assume that the gateway can be responsible for transforming calls to multiple services and returning a new aggregated representation of the data. How does the gateway know about the available models from the microservices?

In my simple example. I have:

- API Gateway
- User Service
- Restaurant Service

**User Service**

This rest service would expose an `/api/users` endpoint

**Model**

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "e-mail": "joe@bloggs.com",
    "lastloggedin": "05/10/2017"
}
```

**Restaurant Service**

This rest service would expose an `/api/dishes` endpoint

**Model**

```
{
    "dishes": [
        {
            "userId": 12345,
            "isActive": true,
            "type": "italian",
            "sub-types": [
                "pizza",
                "pasta"
            ]
        },
        {
            "userId": 12345,
            "isActive": false,
            "type": "american",
            "sub-types": [
                "burgers",
                "steaks"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**API Gateway**

The API Gateway could allow for someone to call `/api/user/12345/dishes` or `/api/dishes` and it would return dishes for cooks. Along with some basic user details.

**Model**

```
{
    "cook": "Joe Bloggs",
    "lastloggedin": "05/10/2017",
    "dishes": [
        {
            "type": "italian",
            "sub-types": [
                "pizza",
                "pasta"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

At this point. I've identified 3 models (i.e. C# classes). 2 from the internal services and 1 for the new representation of the data being returned from the API Gateway. I am unsure as to how the API Gateway knows about the User and Restaurant service models without coupling those models directly to the API Gateway as well. Essentially sharing code between the Gateway and the Microservices, which I believe is not desirable.

Comment: I believe your question is more around the concept of API Chaining. client <--> api 1 <--> api 2 <--> api 3 .This is acceptable but of course there is a risk of the pattern getting broken , so be careful